# If a sequence converges to zero, does the limit of partial sums exists?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Specifically, is the following statement true for $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$?

$$a_n \to 0 \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, \infty\}$$

I know from real analysis that $a_n \to 0$ does not imply that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, but if we allow $\pm \infty$, it seems that the only way for the limit of the partial sums to not exist is if the partial sums are somewhat periodic, which doesn't seem possible given that $a_n \to 0$.

If the statement is true, any reference to a proof / textbook would be helpful. And if the statement is false, a counterexample would be helpful.

Comment: Consider $a_1 = 1$, then add two copies of $-1/2$, then add three copies of $+1/3$, then add four copies of $-1/4$, and continue. The partial sum does not converge.

Comment: I want to give my Example , which I see is similar to what @peterwhy has already given , though those Partial Sums alternate between $+1$ & $0$ & will not converge. **Here is my variation** : [ Start with $+1$ , then add $2^2$ copies of $-1/2$ , then add $3^2$ copies of $+1/3$ , ...  , then add $n^2$ copies of $(-1)^{n+1}/n$ , .... ] : the term tends to $0$ , yet the **Partial Sums are unbounded** , alternating between $+\infty$ & $-\infty$ : **Worst Case Scenario** ! We might try tweaking the Examples a little more , though we can get nothing worse.